# String Random Generator With Probability

Tags: java, arrays, testing

Let say i have a set of Browsers to run the tests on

and

i use the String Random generator like this

```
String randombrowser[]= {"Chrome","Firefox","Edge","Safari"};
Random pickRandomBrowser= new Random();
int i=pickRandomBrowser.nextInt(4);
```

but i want Safari to be least picked and Chrome to be top pick how to achieve that ?

Comment: setting priority in `Random()`  will kill the essence for what it was made.

Comment: It really depends on the `weight` that each element could have. For example, how much more should Safari be picked compared to Chrome?

Comment: “least picked” and “top” are not really useful likelihood specifications. One possibility would be `int i = Math.min((int)Math.abs(pickRandomBrowser.nextGaussian()), 3);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String randombrowser[]= {"Chrome","Chrome","Chrome","Chrome","Firefox","Edge","Safari"};
Random pickRandomBrowser= new Random();
int i=pickRandomBrowser.nextInt(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `EnumeratedDistribution` provided by [commons-math3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.6.1). This will accept a List of Pair values where the key is of type T which in this case is String. It also accepts a Double as the value representing the discrete probability.

```java
        List<Pair<String, Double>> browsers = Arrays.asList(
                Pair.create("Chrome", .5),
                Pair.create("Firefox", .2),
                Pair.create("Edge", .2),
                Pair.create("Safari", .1));

        EnumeratedDistribution<String> distribution =
                    new EnumeratedDistribution<>(browsers);

        String random = distribution.sample();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a selection that is still random but weighted then try this:

```
String browsers[] = {"Chrome","Firefox","Edge","Safari"};
int weightings = { 50, 20, 20, 10 }
int r = new Random().nextInt(100) + 1;
int m = 100;
for(int i = 0; i < weightings.length; i++) {
  m -= weightings[i];
  if(r > m) {
    return browsers[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is just use string with higher probability more times. For example:

```
String randombrowser[]= {"Chrome","Chrome", "Chrome", "Firefox","Edge","Safari"};
Random pickRandomBrowser= new Random();
int i=pickRandomBrowser.nextInt(6);
```

Will return "Chrome" with 3 times higher probability than other